# Why assembling release does not create .tar.gz file?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have followed each step in Deploying with Releases guide on [hex.pm](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/releases.html), so I can run my app with Docker. I thought everything is going good until the moment of deploying to Docker. Building image stopped at lines where I copy tarball release. I found out there is no `.tar.gz` file in my release folder.

I assembled another release locally following mentioned above docs but still, there was not any `.tar.gz` file. Here I attach the files tree:

```
user@machine my_app % tree -L 2 _build/staging/rel/my_app/releases/
_build/staging/rel/my_app/releases/
├── 0.1.0
│   ├── consolidated
│   ├── elixir
│   ├── elixir.bat
│   ├── env.bat
│   ├── env.sh
│   ├── iex
│   ├── iex.bat
│   ├── my_app.rel
│   ├── remote.vm.args
│   ├── runtime.exs
│   ├── start.boot
│   ├── start.script
│   ├── start_clean.boot
│   ├── start_clean.script
│   ├── sys.config
│   └── vm.args
├── COOKIE
└── start_erl.data
```

Also, I made sure I have `steps: [:assemble, :tar]` and `include_executables_for: [:unix]` in `mix.exs` in release section. I tried with specified path and without specifying it, still no result. Another person, on other machine tried assembling release and the result was the same, no tarball file.
Has anyone seen such thing before? I would be grateful for help in finding out what's wrong in here.

Comment: To be able to create a __*.tar.gz__ file you need both programs __tar__ and __gzip__. Make sure you have both.

Comment: @paladin Yes, I have both gzip and tar installed.

Comment: What does your `mix.exs` look like?  Does it include sections for `[:assemble, :tar]`?